# git stash can't find changes after skip-worktree but can't checkout to new branch

Tags: git

Whenever I try to checkout to a new branch I get the following message:

```
$ git co my branch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json
        .vscode/launch.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

If I run `$ git status`

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I saw other posts about git the first error message, but nothing solved my problem, which I believe is more `git update-index --skip-worktree` related.

The only option left was `git checkout -f` which I didn't try because I would rather not force things.

I tried git `git stash save .vscode/launch.json`

```
$ git stash save .vscode/launch.json
No local changes to save
```

These files are among the ones I `git update index --skip-wortree`ed:

```
$ git ls-files -t | grep "S "
S .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json
S .vscode/launch.json
S .vscode/settings.json
S CMakeSettings.json
S msvc_build.bat
```

I saw a few other posts about this error, but none seemed related to `update-index --skip-worktree`

The only option I haven't tried yet is `checkout -f` which I am quite reluctant to use, because I don't like to force things whenever possible.

Comment: The entire point of `--skip-worktree` is that those files don't show up in your `git status` and your stashes. Use `git update-index --no-skip-worktree .vscode/launch.json` to undo the skip-worktree

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling changes to files with --skip-worktree from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690736/handling-changes-to-files-with-skip-worktree-from-another-branch)

Comment: @Omer exactly, I don't want to care about them, so why do I get this error on git checkout?

Comment: `--skip-worktree` mostly means YOUR CHANGES don't get committed/pushed/stashes/status'ed. It does not stop git from letting you know of conflicts between your local state and the remote state. See this: https://compiledsuccessfully.dev/git-skip-worktree/


. Maybe `.gitignore` will be a better option for you if those files are completely personal and meaningless to synchronize inside git

Comment: This is another useful approach (see linked comment, not post): https://old.reddit.com/r/git/comments/7jvuaz/help_with_conflict_between_updateindex/dr9upia/