# Keeping local files with --skip-worktree flag intact on git pull

Tags: git, git-skip-worktree

I have a similar situation like this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690736/handling-changes-to-files-with-skip-worktree-from-another-branch/46004452#46004452)
Basically, I have a file called settings_data.json in my repository. I have --skip-worktree flag set on this file, so that if I make changes on my local machine, I don't accidentally push those changes to production. This is a normal approach for a situation like this, I understand. The problem is, that this file also changes on production independently. In this situation, when I make a pull, I don't want to pull changes for this file on my local repository. I want to completely ignore it. Is there an opinionated approach for a situation like this?

EDIT: I found a "partial solution" based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414968/13086595) answer. I wrote a bash script for git alias, that pulls from remote without comitting, then check out files that has conflict and finally commit changes. But this also pulls changes that I don't want to have locally. I still need something to completely ignore files I don't want to change locally.
This is my alias: `pullbase = "!f() { git pull base main --no-commit; git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U --relative | xargs git checkout HEAD; git commit --no-edit; }; f"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found a solution for my specific case. This is my git alias: `pullbase = "!f() { git pull base main --no-commit; git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M --stat base/main..HEAD templates config/settings_data.json | xargs git checkout HEAD; git log --pretty=format:'%s' -n 1 base/main | git commit -F -; }; f"`

Basiscally what I do is I pull changes from my "base" repository, I check out files that are different between HEAD and remote, then I checkout to HEAD only files I don't want to update. Lastly, I use last commit message from remote and commit my local repo. I hope someone finds this as usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  (You can only get *fairly close*.)

Seriously, this isn't what `--skip-worktree` is for; it's for sparse checkout.  It can be abused this way, or used the way it's designed (via sparse checkout).

> This is a normal approach for a situation like this, I understand.

No, it's not.  This is a Git Frequently Asked Question, specifically [this one](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F):

> How do I tell Git to ignore tracked files?

You're using "Option c":

> - Option c: Make Git ignore changes to the configuration file. There is no automatic centralized way to do that. But on a per-clone basis you can tell Git to do it using either `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` or sparse checkout (see the corresponding section in [git-read-tree(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html) for details). Note that neither feature was designed for that purpose. *Use at own risk.*

(emphasis **theirs**, i.e., the caveat is part of the answer to the frequently asked question).

(I prefer Option "a" myself, whenever it can be used; Option "b" is also good.  Option "c" is terrible: use it only as a last resort.)